# How to open image files with an external application in Dired?

Tags: dired, images

Linux Mint 19, Emacs 26.1
I has different app to show image.Like  Drawing, Image Viewer, XnView.

And from Nemo file manager I success open any images by this app. Nice.

But I want to open image in Dired mode. So in my init.el I has this:

```
(when (require 'openwith nil 'noerror)
  (setq openwith-associations
        (list 
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("doc" "docx" "rtf")) "word" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("mpg" "mpeg" "mp3" "mp4" "avi" "wmv" "wav" "mov" "mkv")) "vlc" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("pdf")) "FoxitReader" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("bmp" "gif" "jpeg" "jpg" "png" "tif")) "xnview" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("rdp")) "Remote Desctop Connection" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("xls" "xlsx")) "excel" '(file))
         ))
  (openwith-mode 1))
```

So when I'm in dired mode and press Enter over image file I get the next message and nothing happend:

```
openwith-file-handler: Opened DEEPSP_little.JPG in external program
```

I want to open image by external app when I'm in dired mode.

Answer (score 1):

Just load standard library `dired-x.el`, customize option `dired-guess-shell-alist-user`, and use `!` in Dired, to open whatever program you want, by default on the marked files or a single file, for whatever image-file extensions you want.

`C-x v dired-guess-shell-alist-user`:

> `dired-guess-shell-alist-user` is a variable defined in `dired-x.el`.
>
> Its value is nil
>
> Documentation:
>
> User-defined alist of rules for suggested commands.
>
> These rules take precedence over the predefined rules in the variable
> `dired-guess-shell-alist-default` (to which they are prepended).
>
> Each element of this list looks like
>
> ```
> (REGEXP COMMAND...)
> ```
>
> where each `COMMAND` can either be a string or a Lisp expression that evaluates
> to a string.  If this expression needs to consult the name of the file for
> which the shell commands are being requested, it can access that file name
> as the variable `file`.
>
> If several `COMMAND`s are given, the first one will be the default
> and the rest will be added temporarily to the history and can be retrieved
> with `M-x previous-history-element` (`M-p`) .
>
> The variable `dired-guess-shell-case-fold-search` controls whether
> REGEXP is matched case-sensitively.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: Hi @Drew You might be tired of copying and pasting this answer to so many questions :-). Personally, I would like to see an example of application via init.el in addition to the manual entry, preferably on usage of libreoffice, to open `xls` or `doc` files from within dired. If you add it to your answer I'd be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @Ajned: If you find that I've posted the same answer to more than one question then please vote to close the relevant questions a duplicates, or let me know and I'll do so, if you don't have the ability to vote for closing a question. As for your request for an example, please post that as a separate question. Someone will answer it (it's not clear to me what the request/question is).

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

I must install app **XnView** by terminal like this:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi

wget http://download.xnview.com/XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb

sudo gdebi XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb
```

And then image success open in Dired mode. And open image by **XnView** app.

Nice.

Not need to do any additional setting in init.el

This is enough:

```
(when (require 'openwith nil 'noerror)
  (setq openwith-associations
        (list 
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("doc" "docx" "rtf")) "word" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("mpg" "mpeg" "mp3" "mp4" "avi" "wmv" "wav" "mov" "mkv")) "vlc" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("pdf")) "FoxitReader" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("bmp" "gif" "jpeg" "jpg" "png" "tif")) "xnview" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("rdp")) "Remote Desctop Connection" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("xls" "xlsx")) "excel" '(file))
         ))
  (openwith-mode 1))
```